# SSIS Config File Not valid error during the scheduling the package

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have Created my one Package with Config file and working very good in BIDS, DTEXEC.EXE and DTEXECUI.exe on remote server But we are using some third Party tool for scheduling the jobs( I cant say). and It wont run in it, it creates an error "the config file is invalid and errors for file location path." what should I do?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The error seems to be related to 3rd party tool which is unable to read the SSIS config file .I assume that the error has nothing to do with the SSIS package .Try to elaborate on how you are executing the ssis package using your tool

Comment: Contact support for the third party tool.

Comment: its same way, it using the DTEXEC.EXE /F " .dtsx loacation" /Config " .dtsconfig Loacation"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your package works fine from BIDS and when you manually execute it, this strongly smells of a permission issue.

You will need to look at the Active Directory user that runs the mysterious third party scheduling tool. You will need to ensure that account (domain\ThirdPartySchedulerService) has read access to `DriveLetter:\path\to\config.dtsconfig`

Also note that if there is an assumption about a drive letter being mapped, it may not apply to service accounts. Similar statement about access to network shares.